# Looping through json in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am reading a JSON from a file in Angular. The content of the file is:

```
{
"mango":
[
{
  "id": 3,
  "image": "Mango1.jpg",
  "text": "I am mango 3"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "image": "Mango2.jpg",
  "text": "I am mango 2"
}
]
```

}

I am reading it in my controller:

```
    $.getJSON("../json/list.json", function (json) {
    $scope.mangoLists = json;
```

When i output to console, it shows the mango object etc. But I am unable to output them to the UI by doing this:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="mango in mangoLists">
        {{mango.text}}
    </div>
```

Please assist.

Comment: And how exactly jQuery will trigger a digest cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also update the view of the controller data after calling `$.getJSON` by using `$scope.$apply()` like so:

```
$.getJSON("../json/list.json", function (json) {
    $scope.mangoLists = json;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

`$scope.$apply()` will trigger a digest cycle which will update the view.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. Why did i have to do this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure why you have to update the view, my guess would be it is because .getJSON is not part of Anugular's api so angular references inside the brackets {{ }} are not watching it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below i think you did something wrong in ng-repeat
i hope this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="mango1 in mangoLists.mango">
        {{mango1.text}}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.mangoLists = {
"mango":
[
{
  "id": 3,
  "image": "Mango1.jpg",
  "text": "I am mango 3"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "image": "Mango2.jpg",
  "text": "I am mango 2"
}
]
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```